# Non ascii value symbols not getting printed

Tags: java, regex, spring, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a string which contains some characters and symbols in which some of them have ascii code and some of them don't; I have tried the below code from which I am able to convert characters but not symbols

```
 String strValue = "Ã – string çöntäining nön äsçii çhäräçtérs couldn’t";
        String str = Normalizer.normalize(strValue, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println( str.replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]","") );
```

output is :

```
Ã – string çöntäining nön äsçii çhäräçtérs couldn’t
A  string containing non ascii characters couldnt
```

I also want "`--`"  and "`'`" from the string value provided.

If i don't do the normalisation it converts my string to

```
? ? string ??nt?ining n?n ?s?ii ?h?r??t?rs couldn?t
```

Comment: both chars (`–` and `’`) **are not** ascii..

Comment: Yes i know but is there any way to get it

Comment: don't replace them with ""?

Comment: but in my code it gets stored with "?" so i was trying this solution

Comment: e.g. : ? ? string ??nt?ining n?n ?s?ii ?h?r??t?rs couldn?t

Comment: @RC. check my edit

Comment: So you want to remove all non-ASCII characters with some exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't replace the wanted chars with `""`:

```
String strValue = "Ã – string çöntäining nön äsçii çhäräçtérs couldn’t";
String str = Normalizer.normalize(strValue, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println( str.replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}–’]","") ); // ie. replace not (ascii or – or ’)
```

Output:

```
Ã – string çöntäining nön äsçii çhäräçtérs couldn’t
A – string containing non ascii characters couldn’t
```

demo: https://ideone.com/6zpYao

Comment: Ohh so dumb of me could have added to regex

Answer (score 0):

If you want those characters to be replaced specifically, you could replace them first.

```
str = str.replaceAll("’", "'");
str = str.replaceAll("–", "--");
str = str.replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}–’]","");
```