# unable to print "÷" symbol in java because non ASCII

Tags: java, ascii

I'm trying to print symbol "÷" in java. Below is my code:

```
System.out.println(N1 + " ÷ "+N2+" = "+(N1/N2));
```

Error as below:

*Your submission contains non ASCII characters, we dont accept submissions with non ASCII characters for this challenge.*

Is there any other ways to print the symbol?

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690641/non-ascii-value-symbols-not-getting-printed

Comment: Any reason why you should not use `/` instead of `÷` ?

Comment: From the error it's not a java issue - it's an issue with some online quiz.

Comment: The error message says it all: it seems you are only allowed to use ASCII chars. So: use a search engine to identify the characters that are ASCII. You could find https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html for example. And ... yes, the only "division like" char you find in there is `/`.

Comment: And yes, this, in the end, has nothing to do with Java itself. It is a restriction in your learning environment or whatever service you are dealing there with is imposing.

Comment: Otherwise, you could try to use the Unicode *escape sequence* (`\u00F7`) and see if that works.

Comment: `N1 + " \u00F7 "+N2+" = "+(N1/N2)` try it if tis work

Answer (score 1):

This is not the problem of *Java*, the problem is the terminal setting on host machine.

Most probably in the host machine's terminal doesn't support *UTF-8* and while submitting the code you are getting this issue!.

But since it is non-ascii character and you don't have control over host machine, **there is no other way**.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double N1 = 10;
    double N2 = 2;
    System.out.println("N1 ÷ N2 = " + (N1/N2));
}
```

Comment: Unlikely to be different from the code in the question...